# Table is using more than 100% width of its parent element, how can this be fixed by CSS only?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a root div using 100% width and I want all children not to overlap (`overflow:hidden`) and also not to use more width than this 100%.

This works fine when I work with inner `<div>`s, but if `<table>`s are used, the table gets too wide, using more than the parent 100% `div`.

How can this be fixed while keeping the `table`?

Here is the **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLt1mec8/2/)**.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: just add in your css #wrapper > div {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

Comment: Change `id="item"` and `#item` to `class="item"` and `.item` you cannot use `id` on more than one element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should give `word-break: break-word;` for td text  , because the text is a large length, or you can give td text as `word-break: break-all;` for breaking the text.

**updated css code**

```
#wrapper table td{
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kLt1mec8/3/

Answer (score 5):

if you add the following styles, it should fix your problem:

```
#wrapper table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
#wrapper table td {
  overflow:auto; /* can be hidden if you want to hide it */
}
```

Updated code:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
#item {
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper table {
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-width: 1px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#wrapper table td {
  overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper table td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 10%;
}
#wrapper table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="item">
    This is a normal text box where the width gets preserved correctly.
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    this div contains a very long word, e.g. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Simca_1300_Serie_1_rear_20110114.jpg and the width does correctly not use more than 100% of the parnet's width.
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col2 mit viel Text https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Simca_1300_Serie_1_rear_20110114.jpg the width gets too wide! How can I make this DIV to be not wider than the parent?</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add `word-break: break-all;` to your `td`